# Python : Try uploading three times if timeout occurs

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, client-server, urllib2, urllib

I am uploading an image file to the server but when timeout occurs it terminates the upload and move to the next. i want to upload the image again if timeout occurs. I want to try to upload three times at max.and after three attempts if still timeout occurs then throw an exception and move to the next.

here's my code

```
def upload(filename2,sampleFile,curr_time,curr_day,username,password,user_id):

    register_openers()
    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"sampleFile": open(sampleFile), "name": filename2, "userID": user_id,'date': curr_day,'time': curr_time, 'username': username,'password': password})

    request = urllib2.Request("http://videoupload.hopto.org:5001/api/Synclog", datagen, headers)

    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = 20)
        html=response.read()                
    except URLError , e:
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print ('Reason: ', e.reason)                
        elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print ('Error code: ', e.code)
    except Exception:
        print ('generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())
    return
```

Comment: You could call `upload` recursively with an `attempt` parameter or use a loop and break if no exceptions occur.

Comment: @t.m.adam how do i use it in a loop I mean loop would break automatically after exception will occur

Comment: It won't because you catch exceptions.